# Buttons do not appear with the ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have a `LinearLayout` that is supposed to show vertically an image and 3 `Buttons`.

However, as soon as I put the image, I can't see the buttons. Is there a logical reason for this behavior ?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ImageView
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:maxHeight="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logooutlast" />

<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/buttonWalktrough" />

<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/buttonFullCompletion" />

<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/buttonInsaneMode" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe they're just being pulled down due to the height of the `ImageView` and you have not enabled scrolling on your layout.

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: But my picture is only taking 1/5 portion of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `ScrollView` as the parent view in xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <!-- Other views here -->

   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I have now used ScrollView as you have told me. The buttons are only appearing when I scroll down a lot. Is that normal even if the picture is only taking a small portion of the screen ?

Comment: If the resolution of picture is small, the buttons should appear after no/few scrolls.